# WPF: How to bind to another control's child's child properties

Tags: wpf, xaml

Problem:
I have two separate objects in a grid: A TextBox, and a TextBlock 
I want the TextBlock to be visible when the vertical scrollbar of the TextBox is visible.

**Update : The vertical scrollbar visibility should be set to Auto, so it is the actual visibility (see below) we want to trigger on.**

Approach:
The template of the TextBox seems to contain a Grid named PART_InnerGrid which in turn contains a scrollviewer named PART_ContentHost. This scrollviewer contains a property called ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility which is of type Visibility.
I have tried creating a trigger on the TextBlock, but I have been unable to construct a proper binding path. How would I do this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TB1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" MinHeight="40"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

<TextBlock Text="VISIBLE" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TB1, Path=(PART_InnerGrid).(PART_ContentHost).ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind both of their visibility to a boolean property and use a Converter to convert the boolean to a visibility value.

Their visibility would look like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding YourBoolProperty, Converter={StaticResource Converters_BoolToVisConverter}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would work if I didnt need the visibility of the scrollbar to be set to Auto in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="text" Width="50" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="TextBox"/>
    <TextBlock Text="ScrollViewer visible">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would work if I didnt need the visibility of the scrollbar to be set to Auto in the first place.